# What is Pods-App.framework and it is a umbrella framework?

Tags: cocoapods

I have a question about whether Pod-App.framework in `/Build/Product` directory, is it an umbrella framework?

I just found Pods_App.the framework has a header `Pods-App-umbrella.h` and searched around did not get more info.

As I know Umbrella framework may have a sub-framework in the directory.